# matplotlib error: UserWarning: could not find rc file

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have the following very simple code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

x = np.random.randn(60) 
y = np.random.randn(60)
z = [np.random.random() for _ in range(60)]

fig = plt.figure()
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2)

ax0 = plt.subplot(gs[0, 0])
plt.scatter(x, y, s=20)

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0, 1])
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu_r')
plt.scatter(x, y, s=20 ,c=z, cmap=cm, vmin=0, vmax=1)
cbaxes = fig.add_axes([0.6, 0.12, 0.1, 0.02]) 
plt.colorbar(cax=cbaxes, ticks=[0.,1], orientation='horizontal')

fig.tight_layout()

out_png = '/home/user/image_out.png'
plt.savefig(out_png, dpi=150)
plt.close()
```

If I run it on my machine it works except for a warning:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py:1533: UserWarning: This figure includes Axes that are not compatible with tight_layout, so its results might be incorrect.
  warnings.warn("This figure includes Axes that are not "
```

But if I run it on a cluster it exits with the following error:

```
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/__init__.py:611: UserWarning: Could not find matplotlibrc; using defaults
  warnings.warn('Could not find matplotlibrc; using defaults')
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/__init__.py:698: UserWarning: could not find rc file; returning defaults
  warnings.warn(message)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "colorbar.py", line 7, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 23, in <module>
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/figure.py", line 18, in <module>
    from axes import Axes, SubplotBase, subplot_class_factory
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 14, in <module>
    import matplotlib.axis as maxis
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axis.py", line 10, in <module>
    import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1325, in <module>
    _rebuild()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1275, in _rebuild
    fontManager = FontManager()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 962, in __init__
    paths = [os.path.join(rcParams['datapath'], 'fonts', 'ttf'),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 77, in join
    elif path == '' or path.endswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

What is going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: First thing: don't mix pyplot and OO interface. I doubt that this is the cause of your problem, but it can give unwanted effects. E.g: `ax0 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0]); ax0.scatter(x, y, s=20)`

Comment: BTW: the two warnings are different issues, and the title relates only to one of them

Comment: Hi Francesco, the first warning is really not important since the code works fine with it. It's the second one that I need to resolve.

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano I very much disagree, mixing the state machine and OO style is fine (and can make your life easier).  A vast majority of the `plt.*()` calls boil down to `gca().*(); plt.draw_when_idle()` so I think you are making a distinction with out a difference.

Comment: @tcaswell: I don't like mixing the two when writing code. I see the point in mixing when it comes to interactive plotting (although personally I don't use it much, with the exception of `plt.draw()`)

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano I would also guess you make heavy use of `plt.figure()` instead of dealing directly with the figure managers or `Figure` directly.  I agree that using the OO style is easier to read, more portable, better in almost every way, but I would not discourage mixing and matching the interfaces when appropriate (as you did in your answer with `plt.figure` and `plt.subplots` ;))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The first warning is related with the way `axes` and `subplots` are created. `axes` are created specifying the size, while `subplots` puts the axes in a regular grid.

   So `tight_layout` cannot resize `axes`, as it does with `subplots` and you get the warning. Therefore using `axes`, `subplots` and `tight_layout` might need a lot of tweaking in `fig.add_axes([0.6, 0.12, 0.1, 0.02])`
2. The error that you get when running on the cluster looks to me related to some problem with the matplotlib installation. The warning is what it is: matplotlib does not find any `matplotlibrc` file in any of the [standard places](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html), so it falls back to default (hard coded) parameters. Then it expects to find a parameter `'datapath'`. But is not there (or wrongly defined to be `None`) so `rcParams['datapath']` returns `None`.

   The parameter is then passed to `os.path.join` wich expects strings, not `NoneType`.

   You can see if [getting a `matplotlibrc` file](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#a-sample-matplotlibrc-file) and putting in the your current directory or `~/.config/matplotlib` can solve your problem.

   An other thing that you should do is to check the version of matplotlib and if the version that you run is the one that you think you are using running

   ```
   python -c 'import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.__version__); print(matplotlib.__file__)'
   ```

ps: I dont' think that you need `gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2)` at all, unless you then do something extra with the axes.
You get the exact same answer if you do

```
fig = plt.figure(...)
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(122)
```

or

```
fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, ...)
```

Comment: Adding a `matplotlibrc` file appears to have fixed that issue but now I'm getting another one, probably related with the fact that I use version 1.2.1 and the cluster has version 1.1.1rc2 installed. In any case, I'm marking this answer as accepted since it correctly addressed the problem. Thank you Francesco!

Comment: Thank you. Might be that in `1.1.1rc2` the keyword `datapath` was required in `matplotlib/font_manager.py` but not added in the default rc params. Good luck with the new problem.